# Getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
while executing this code.

```
 const map  = (array, callback) => {
    return [callback(array[0])].concat(map(array.slice(1),callback));
}
var lower = map(['A','B','C'],function (val) {
    return val.toLowerCase()
});
console.log(lower);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if array `length` is `1` then only return the element because there are no other elements left.

```js
const map  = (array, callback) => {
    if(array.length === 1) return [callback(array[0])]
    return [callback(array[0])].concat(map(array.slice(1),callback));
}
var lower = map(['A','B','C'],function (val) {
    return val.toLowerCase()
});
console.log(lower);
```

It seems that you want to create your own `map()`. In think you loop is better than recursion.

```js
const map  = (array, callback) => {
    let res = []
    for(let i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
      res[i] = callback(array[i],i)
    }
    return res;
}
var lower = map(['A','B','C'],function (val) {
    return val.toLowerCase()
});
console.log(lower);
```

#### Why OP's code donot work?

The code in question uses recursion. And whenever we use recursive approach we should have a condition to return the function with calling it again.

- Now consider then the array `length` is `1`
- then `array.slice(1)` will return `[]`
- an empty array will be passed to `map()`.
- For an empty array `array[0]` will `undefined
- then `undefined` will be passed to `callback`
- `undefined.toLowerCase` throws error.

#### Conclusion

You don't need to run the part  `.concat(map(array.slice(1),callback))` when only one element is left in array. Because there is noting more to `concat()`

Comment: Thankyou sir that helped. But can you explain why are we checking for the length of array. @maheerali

Comment: @sharad Glad to know that you want to reason. I have updated the answer with the reason why you should check length.